# Multiply two symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$r, s, t, c_0, c_1, c_2$ are real numbers and the sequence $$\{V_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$$ is determined in this way: $$V_0 = c_0,\qquad V_1 = c_1, \qquad V_2 = c_2,\qquad V_n = rV_{n-1} + sV_{n-2} + tV_{n-3} \quad \text{for} \quad \text{n > 2}$$

For all $n > 1$ calculate:

$$\left|\begin{pmatrix}
    V_{n+2}  & V_{n+1} & V_{n} \\
    V_{n+1}  & V_{n} & V_{n-1} \\
    V_{n}  & V_{n-1} & V_{n-2} 
\end{pmatrix}\right| \cdot \left|\begin{pmatrix}
    V_{4}  & V_{3} & V_{2} \\
    V_{3}  & V_{2} & V_{1} \\
    V_{2}  & V_{1} & V_{0} 
\end{pmatrix}\right|^{-1}$$

So, these matrices are symmetriс and I think that some properties of symmetric matrix should be used, but I don't know which.

Comment: manabou11’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630824/multiply-two-symmetric-matrices/3630897#3630897)
is correct and detailed. In particular, it takes into account the recurrence for $\{V_n\}$. Also I remark that it the value required to calculate is determined iff $\det(W_0)\ne 0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky it doesn't take into account that formula for $V_{n}$ works only for n>2. It doesn't take into account that $V_{0}$ = $c_{0}$, $V_{1}$ = $c_{1}$, $V_{2}$ = $c_{2}$

Comment: The recurrent formula for $V_n$ for $n>2$ is sufficient to provide the recurrent formula for $W_n$ for each $n\ge 1$ (since in the latter is used the recurrent formula for $V_{n+2}$). As far as $\det W_0\ne 0$, the initial values of $V_i$ do not matter, because they collapse in the final expression $\det (W_{n-2})\det (W_0)^{-1}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky are $w_{n}$ and  $W_{n}$ matrices?

Comment: @AlexRavsky  Like what does this square brackets mean?

Comment: Right, $w_n$ is a $3\times 1$ matrix and $W_n$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. The square brackets just join components of the matrices together. Components of $w_n$ are $1\times 1$ matrices and components of $W_n$ are $3\times 1$ matrices,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us first write the recursive relation in matrix form.
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{n+2} \\
V_{n+1} \\
V_n
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
r & s & t \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{n+1} \\
V_n \\
V_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Let us denote
$$w_n = \begin{bmatrix}
V_{n+2} \\
V_{n+1} \\
V_n
\end{bmatrix}, \quad A = \begin{bmatrix}
r & s & t \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can rewrite the relation above in a more compact form
$$w_n = A w_{n-1}$$
Further, define
$$W_n = \begin{bmatrix}
w_{n+2}, w_{n+1}, w_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The formula for $W_n$ is
$$
W_n = \begin{bmatrix}
A w_{n+1}, A w_n, A w_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
= AW_{n-1} = \cdots = A^n W_0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\det(W_n) = \det(A^n) \det(W_0) = \det(A)^n \det(W_0) = t^n \det(W_0)
$$
What you are looking for is actually equal to
$$
\det(W_{n-2}) \det(W_0)^{-1} = t^{n-2}
$$

Comment: and why you write that Wn = [wn, w(n+1), w(n+2)], shouldn't it be [wn, w(n-1), w(n-2)]?

Comment: and what is this topic called in algebra?

Comment: @manabou11, I changed the final result. The order of the columns does not matter. You can define $W_n$ in your preferred way. I don't know if there is such a topic in algebra, but this trick is common in ODE, and it helps you reduce a higher-order linear ODE into a lower-order one.

Comment: thanks, but i still don't understand why second matrix is equal to W(n-2), i think that it should be equal to W2 isn't it?

Comment: I redefined $W_n$ so that it fits your question perfectly. Try to write done $W_{n-2}$ and $W-0$ entry-by-entry. You will see that they are the same matrices as in the problem.

Comment: and how you find matrix A? is there an easy way for it maybe a formula or you just see it?

Comment: The first row of $A$ is simply the recursive relation. All the other rows are trivial identities like $V_n = V_n$. You only need to find the correct place for that $1$. Exercise: Come up with another (linear) recursive relation, try to derive the matrix $A$.

Comment: thanks i got it, its strange that they used symmetric matrix though, maybe there is one more option which leads to the same answer

Comment: @manabou11, I don't think the symmetric form is very useful. The reason why I defined $W_n = \left[ w_{n}, w_{n+1}, w_{n+2} \right]$ is because this makes $W_n$ a Toeplitz matrix. I found the Toeplitz form more natural. It doesn't help much solve the problem directly though